# How to check Equal Sign in string using REGEX in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to check string which look like following

1st  `radius = 120`

and

2nd  `radius = 'value'`

Here is my code

```
v1 = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]+\s[=]\s[A-Za-z]+$");
if (v1.IsMatch(singleLine))`
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

Using `@"^[A-Za-z]+\s[=]\s[A-Za-z]+$"` this expression 2nd string is matched but not first and when used this `@"^[A-Za-z]+\s[=]\s\d{0,3}$"` then only matched first one.

And i also want to check for `radius = 'val01'`

Comment: Do these three examples cover all of the possible cases? My point is: you should mention what are the matching conditions... these three cases don't seem to me like all of the possible ones. i.e.: is the number in the RHS always a three digit number?

Comment: How about [`^[A-Za-z]+\s=\s(?:[A-Za-z]+|\d{1,3}|[A-Za-z]+\d{1,2})$`](https://regex101.com/r/s4zS8T/1), using some alternation and based on what you showed us. You can lift some restrictions based on your needs I guess.

Comment: Use `@"^[A-Za-z]+\s=\s(?:'[A-Za-z0-9]+'|\d+)$"`

Comment: The pattern `^[A-Za-z]+\s[=]\s[A-Za-z]+$` that you tried does not match the second string `radius = 'value'` If you do not mean to match the single quotes, you can add matching digits to the second character class `^[A-Za-z]+\s[=]\s[A-Za-z0-9]+$` https://regex101.com/r/NuVFQC/1

Answer (score 0):

Basing on your effort, it looks as if you were trying to come up with

```cs
^[A-Za-z]+\s=\s(?:'[A-Za-z0-9]+'|\d{1,3})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VKea8o/3/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z]+` - one or more ASCII letters
- `\s=\s` -  a `=` char enclosed with single whitespace chars
- `(?:'[A-Za-z0-9]+'|\d{1,3})` - a non-capturing group matching either

  - `'[A-Za-z0-9]+'` - `'`, then one or more ASCII letters or digits and then a `'`
  - `|` - or
  - `\d{1,3}` - one, two or three digits
- `$` - end of string (actually, `\z` is safer when it comes to validating as there can be no final trailing newline after `\z`, and there can be such a newline after `$`, but it also depends on how you obtain the input).

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern you tried `^[A-Za-z]+\s[=]\s[A-Za-z]+$` matches the second string `radius = 'value'`, that means that `'value'` consists of only chars A-Za-z.

In that case, you could either add matching digits to the second character class:

```
^[A-Za-z]+\s=\s[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

---

If you either want to match 1-3 digits or at least a single char A-Za-z followed by optional digits:

```
^[A-Za-z]+\s=\s(?:[0-9]{1,3}|[A-Za-z]+[0-9]*)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Za-z]+\s=\s` Match the first part with chars A-Za-z and the `=` sign (***Note** that `=` does not have to be between square brackets)*
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[0-9]{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits *(You can use `\d{0,3}` but that will also match an emtpy string due to the `0`)*
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Za-z]+[0-9]*` Match 1+ chars A-Za-z followed by optional digits
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5bA-Za-z%5d%2b%5cs%3d%5cs%28%3f%3a%5b0-9%5d%7b1%2c3%7d%7c%5bA-Za-z%5d%2b%5b0-9%5d*%29%5cr%3f%24&i=radius+%3d+120%0d%0aradius+%3d+value%0d%0aradius+%3d+val01&o=m)